# Virtuoso bulk insert failed

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, virtuoso, turtle-rdf

I'm using Windows 11 and I was trying to make a bulk insert with OpenLink Virtuoso Open Source edition. I was following this guide: https://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_ld_dir_all/.
I updated the `virtuoso.ini` file with 'a proper' `DirsAllowed` parameter (`<path>` is something like `C:\\Users\\user\\Git\\Projects\\rdf_repository`)

```
DirsAllowed        = ., <path>
```

But I'm having troubles nonetheless, with the following error message.

> The statement execution did not return a result set.
> SQLState: 42000
> Message: FA003: Access to  is denied due to access control in ini file

Is there any alternative to `isql.exe` or Conductor? A tool to import RDF Turtle or graph files?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation page](https://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_ld_dir_all/) you linked to is specifically focused on a single function, `ld_dir_all()`. You may find better results by following [this guide to the Bulk Loader](https://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoader), which does *mention* `ld_dir_all()` but covers several other things along the way.

That said, since you're getting an error about the `<path>` value you've put in the INI `DirsAllowed`, we probably need to see exactly what you've put there, and the exact error message, rather than you masking the `<path>` strings in either value.

A common cause of this error is using one or more directory values that are not Windows-appropriate. This Windows-appropriate value may provide the clue you need --

```
.;D:\my\favorite\directory
```

Also note that if your directory path includes mixed-case and/or space characters, you may need to wrap each directory path (between semicolons `;`) in double-quotes (e.g., "D:\my favorite\directory").

In some environments, you even need to add the data source directory (e.g., `D:\my\favorite\directory`) to your `%PATH%` environment variable.

If the above doesn't get you rolling and/or you're concerned about posting details to the public web, you may prefer to [open a Support Case](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/SupportWeb/) through our website, rather than conversing here or on [our public Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/). Note that priority handling of Support Cases is reserved for users of our Enterprise Edition and/or holding an active support contract, so while we *will* respond to you, it may take a day or more between our responses.